# How to proove that the electromagnetic wave is transverse?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

From the solution of wave equation we got `E = f(z+ct)+g(z-ct)`. How IS the function f or g are transverse?

Comment: The statement that an electromagnetic wave is transversal cannot be proven because it is not true in general and the existence of a longitudinal component depends on the boundary conditions.

Comment: Do Hertz's experiment https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Hertz#Electromagnetic_waves.

Comment: @JohnDoty Hertz's most brilliant experiment clearly falls under the category of "*the theory tells what you can observe*" for if the antenna is "large" relative to the wavelength and the transmit/receive distance is "small" relative to the wavelength then you do get strong longitudinal component...

Comment: @hyportnex Sure. And Hertz's antenna theory includes longitudinal fields. Still, the concept of a transverse wave is a useful model.

Comment: @JohnDoty you are absolutely right my point is just reading the question I doubt the questioner would understand the answer offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf E = \mathbf f(z + ct) + \mathbf g(z - ct)$ is the sum of two plane waves.

In the vacuum: $$\nabla . \mathbf E = 0 \implies \frac {\partial E_x}{\partial x} + \frac {\partial E_y}{\partial y} + \frac {\partial E_z}{\partial z} = 0 $$

As the $x$ and $y$ components are zero because the equation has no dependency on that variables, we conclude that $$\frac {\partial E_z}{\partial z} = 0$$

That means: any $E_z$ of the wave must be constant, and so it is not part of it, but only a possible existing static field. Any oscillating field must be transversal to the plane wave.

Comment: what you have written is true for a homogeneous plane wave but is not true in a waveguide although divE=0 within it everywhere. boundary conditions matter.

Comment: Sure. It valid for the equation of plane waves mentioned in the question.

Comment: The question is about a plane progressive wave in vaccum. So the purpose of this work is to explain the existence of the wave in the vacuum and its behavior, isn't it?